# Display bitmap in textview

Tags: android

I am trying to display bitmap in textview. Below code shows the bitmap in the textview using R.drawable.bitmap_name. How can I pass a bitmap in SpannableStringBuilder? Thanks

```
 SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
            builder.append(text).append(" ");
            builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(MyActivity.this, R.drawable.image_1 ), builder.length() - 1, builder.length(), 0);
            myTv.setText(builder);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For instance like this:

```
builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(yourBitmap), builder.length() - 1, builder.length(), 0);
```

`ImageSpan` has following constructors:

```
new ImageSpan(Bitmap b)
new ImageSpan(Bitmap b, int verticalAlignment)
new ImageSpan(Context context, Bitmap b)
new ImageSpan(Context context, Bitmap b, int verticalAlignment)
```